# How do I make a self contained app for windows in JavaFx?

Tags: maven, javafx

I developed an JavaFx app with Maven. I'm developing it on Ubuntu OS so when I run mvn clean jfx:native I get a .deb file. How can I make a windows installer?

My pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.company.app_name.Main</mainClass>
                    <jvmArgs>
                        <argument>-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true</argument>
                        <argument>-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true</argument>
                        <argument>-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx</argument>
                    </jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build it (run `mvn clean jfx:native`) on Windows. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40938_01/doc.74/e40142/build_japps.htm#NBDAG2508 (the build tools used are platform specific).